# Multibranch pipeline with remote Jenkinsfile plugin

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I have a 'multibranch pipeline' with the 'remote Jenkinsfile' plugin. This plugin allows you to separate the application source code and pipeline files. You can call a remote repository where you have the Jenkinsfiles. So far so good. Now I need to load a properties file in the Jenkinsfile, and this properties file is located in the Jenkinsfile repository. When examining the workspace, I don't find the Jenkinsfile repository; I only see the app repository.

Is there any way to load the properties file for the Jenkinsfile?

I tried to use readTRusted but no result...

Comment: You could use GitSCM plugin (or just plain git commands) to pull the repo that has the property file.

Comment: "As a workaround, it's not bad. However, I want to consider another friendly solution because with the Remote Jenkinsfile plugin, Jenkins is able to map Jenkinsfile..."